# Getting tokens in a private Iota testnet

Tags: iota

I am trying to deploy my own IOTA testnet using **iri** and the **API** but I am unable to get any balance in my accounts. How can I configure the testnet to have some tokens at start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a good tutorial for deploying an own IOTA testnet with account balances here:

> https://github.com/schierlm/private-iota-testnet

In short:

1. First, a snapshot is created that contains accounts equipped with IOTA tokens.
2. The next step is to start iri using the snapshot you just created (although iri needs to be slightly modified)

Comment: I tried this tutorial but I wasn´t able to get any tokens either, but I´ll try again. Thanks!